# Filter by tag JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, filter, tags

**When I click a tag then the tag entered to text search and then another article that have a same tag will appear**, how I can get it with javascript?

I have tried to search and I found some but nothing helping me and but I confused about my keyword, someone can give link or code?

[image: tagging]

Comment: Hi. [You're going to have to make your question much clearer if you want us to help you.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) For example, edit your question with some of the relevant HTML and JS code you've already written.

Comment: thank you @Andy i'll fix it latter :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could you share a HTML snippet of your code ?

```
var searchbar = document.querySelector('header input.search');
var searchTerms = document.querySelectorAll('.my-selector-tag-chip');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(searchTerms, function (itemSearchTerm) {
itemSearchTerm.addEventListener('click', function (button) {
  searchbar.value = this.innerText.toLowerCase();
  searching();
});
```

The searching method is the launch of the search (inner the page content or for the whole website). You can add a listener for your search input, so the searching method call is useless.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer but i'm confused what should i share because i not much understand i'm just copy from code before :(

Comment: ``var searchbar = document.querySelector('header input.search');``is for selected your input, change the selector (you can use #searchbar selector for example)

``var searchTerms = document.querySelectorAll('.my-selector-tag-chip');`` is for your tags, when you click on an element with this class, the action will be launched. So the content text will be copied in the searchbar and then the search will be done

Comment: how script for angularJS? its same or not? because my brother said that I should use ng-click on the tag for filtering, oh please help me :(

Comment: For angular, it's different. use ng-click=search('tag') on "button" where tag is the  same content as the button element. The search method could be resolved with many solutions. (data-binding + event) or broadcast an event with some parameters